# Python Function Define of HTML Table Code

Tags: python, html

I am trying to create define a function that will create HTML tables from input CSV files. The code works by itself but I cannot get it to work correctly as a function. It is:

```
def write(in_name):
    table = ''
    with open(in_name, encoding="utf-8-sig") as csvFile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvFile, delimiter=',')
        table = '<tr>{}</tr>'.format(''.join(['<td>{}</td>'.format(header) for header in reader.fieldnames]))
        for row in reader:
            table_row = '<tr>'
            for fn in reader.fieldnames:
                table_row += '<td>{}</td>'.format(row[fn])
            table_row += '</tr>'
            table += table_row
    table = table.replace(u'\xa0', u' ')

write("2016motogp.csv")

table
```

Which just gives the output ' '.

Ideally I would like to choose the output name so I could save multiple tables to be input in various areas.

If anyone could help me it would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the function wrong. First, change the name of the function (`write` is used by Python),then append this to the end of the function:

```
return table #Functions can return values,just like in math
```

Now, we store the value obtained in a variable:

```
result = write_table("2016motogp.csv")
```

Now, just:

```
 print(result)
```